# How to re-order the angularjs ngTable pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I'm using angularjs 1.5.7 in my current project. I use ngTable almost everywhere in this project. Lately I've been asked to change the way we show pagination on top of each table. Our current format:

[image]

We want to have:

[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-switch="page.type">
        <a ng-switch-when="first" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="" translate>TABLE.FIRST</a>
        <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="" translate>TABLE.PREVIOUS</a>
        <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="" translate>TABLE.NEXT</a>
        <a ng-switch-when="last" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="" translate>TABLE.LAST</a>
    </li>

    <li ng-if="params.pages < 2" ng-class="{'disabled':true}" ng-repeat="n in ['«','1','»']">
        <a type="button" ng-click="" href="" ng-bind="n"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it in order of: First>Prev>Next>Last. What I get instead is:
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to force it to appear in the order I want?

Thanks

Comment: I know I can have a workaround by using 4 separate li tag that use 4 ng-repeat; but that seems to be inefficient!

Comment: Is this simply because the `pages` collection is not ordered properly?

Comment: @Lex Not sure, but this is my getData function: `getData: function($defer, params) {
            var data = $scope.myCollection;           
            params.total(data.length);
            $scope.tableParams.pages = Math.ceil(this.total / params.count());
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));            
        }`

Comment: So, the question is how can I reorder ngTable's pages array? That's ngTable library code!

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngTable, but I'm still not seeing where the `pages` object in `ng-repeat="page in pages"` is coming from. Without knowing where that's coming from or what, specifically, it contains it's hard to answer. What is the exact structure of the `page` object in the `pages` collection? Does it have a property that you could sort on?

Comment: pages is coming from: $scope.tableParams.pages = Math.ceil(this.total / params.count()); Which is inherited from Angular's ngTable library. This library has a generatePagesArray function where each page is an anonymous object that has some properties like 'type' and 'number' but NOT a 'sorting' property!

Answer (score 1):

Given that there doesn't seem to be any way to sort the pages collection using native properties, you can easily create your own function to do so. Here is an example of a `$scope`-level function that you can pass to the `orderBy` directive. It's not the most elegant thing, but essentially I'm converting the text of the `page.type` to a numeric equivalent to allow `orderBy` to sort in your desired order.

**Update**: I added a listing without the `orderBy` to demonstrate that it really is performing the sort when using `orderBy`.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.orderPages = (page) => {
      switch (page.type) {
        case 'first':
          return 1;
        case 'prev':
          return 2;
        case 'next':
          return 3;
        case 'last':
          return 4;
      }
    }

    $scope.pages = [{
      type: 'last',
      text: '>>'
    }, {
      type: 'first',
      text: '<<'
    }, {
      type: 'next',
      text: '>'
    }, {
      type: 'prev',
      text: '<'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Without orderBy:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">{{page.text}}</li>
  </ul>
  
  With orderBy:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages | orderBy: orderPages">{{page.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```